# How to write commands to terminal using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to do something like , if i type something in textbox that command would get executed completely 
like this [image]

ie the ~Desktop should be displayed to write next command.

but with my code im getting this also there is an error

[image]

as you can see ls command gets executed half in second case 
my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter
import subprocess

import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class HackBar:

  def __init__(self,master):

      frame=Frame(master,width = 600,height = 250)
      #frame.pack()

      def printconsole(event):
          print("hello dere ")
      def retrieve_input(event):
          input = self.Text.get("1.0",'end-1c')
          #print(input)
          #subprocess.call(input,shell=TRUE)
          subprocess.Popen(input)
          root.quit()
          #root = Tk()
          #print p.communicate()

      self.button1 = Button(root,text = "Execute")
      self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",retrieve_input);
      self.button1.grid(row = 0,sticky = E)

      self.button2 = Button(root,text = "  Quit   ")
      self.button2.bind("<Button-1>",printconsole);
      self.button2.grid(row = 1,sticky = E)

      self.Text = Text(root,height =4)
      self.Text.grid(row = 0,column = 1,rowspan=2)

menu = Menu(root)
def AboutDialog():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('About','For any issues or suggestion contact rushic24@gmail.com ')
root.config(menu = menu)
submenu1 = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=submenu1)
submenu1.add_command(label = "About",command = AboutDialog)

b = HackBar(root)
root.mainloop()
```

i think i need to use the root.quit() and would again need to start root ,
but it is giving the above error.
Any alternate method would also work.

Comment: I can't replicate the error, it works fine. Please check that the code posted in your question is actually the same as that which produces the error.

Comment: BTW: button has `Button(..., command=function_name)` and you don't need `bind('<Button-1>', function_name)`

Comment: @mhawke Refer the images , in normal terminal if i type ls , it shows the directory and ends there , and default directory like ~root is shown.        Whereas by code if i pass ls it shows the files but it freezes there , the default dir ~root is not shown in terminal

Comment: @user2351509: why would the bash terminal prompt be shown? All your code does is to execute a command via `Popen()`, it does not execute a shell. If you want to display a terminal prompt you will have to add the code to do that, as well as the code to collect the subprocess output (you could use [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or similar for that).

Comment: @mhawke Fortunately , the bash terminal is the one through which im running the program ./t4.py.   By the way can you provide me link to open a terminal prompt  and collect subprocess output ? Any tutorial?

Comment: @user2351509: You have used the keyword "input", First change that.